# Capture groups using reuse patterns

Tags: javascript, regex

This is a problem on freeCodecamp that I've been stuck on for days now. The regex should return true for numbers that repeat only 3 times in a string. That being said the numbers should be seperated by 2 spaces. Here is a solution that I found which should return false to `mystring`

```
let myString = '42 42 42 42'
let myRegex = /(\d\d+)(\s)\1\2\1/
let result = myRegex.test(myString) //True
```

This is the solution that I got from get `get a hint` but even this is not working. It passes all of the tests except 1. It is supposed to return false because the number in the string repeats itself 4 times and not 3

Comment: Can the string contain any other numbers? Eg `1 2 2 2`, which would be a match, or is that not possible?

Comment: It should not be a match. All numbers should be the same by the way. e.g.) `'1 1 1'` is true but `'1 2 2'` is false.

Comment: The number should only repeat 3 times. No more. And no less.

Answer (score 3):

By using start `^` and end `$` tags you can stop the re-use computation after a certain amount of re-uses like this:

```
/^(\d+)(\s)\1\2\1$/
```

Groups:
1: `(\d+)` Check for one or more digits.
2: `(\s)` Check for a single white-space.

Re-use groups:
`\1` Re-use the digits group.
`\2` Re-use the white-space group.
`\1` Re-use the digits group again. before ending the check with `$`

First we "use" the 2 groups, then we "re-use"  group 1, then group 2 and lastly group 1 again.

<------ use ------->|<--------- re-use -------->
digits whitespace digits whitespace digits

Answer (score 2):

I passed the test on freeCodecamp using this

```
/^(\d+)\s\1\s\1$/
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the matched part isn't followed by the number, which can be done with negative lookahead for the backreference, or by anchoring the end of the pattern to the end of the string. But there's another problem - if the regex engine *starts* at the beginning of the 2nd number, eg:

```
42 42 42 42
   ^
```

Then the pattern will pass, when it shouldn't. So, make sure to anchor the pattern to the beginning too.

```
^(\d+)(?: \1){2}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/jnTPbw/1

Answer (score 0):

From the lesson's objective:

> Use capture groups in reRegex to match numbers that are repeated only
> three times in a string, each separated by a space.

As I understand the objective is to match the same numbers separated by space that repeat only three times anywhere in a string. I would assume that means that the group of the matching numbers could be preceded by anything except the same number and space, and followed by anything except the space and the same number.

So the match for string

> 42 42 42 42

would be false, but match for string

> 23 **42 42 42** 34

should be true.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily write this code.

```js
let repeatNum = "42 42 42";
let reRegex = /^(\d+) \1 \1$/; // Change this line
let result = reRegex.test(repeatNum);
result = repeatNum.match(reRegex)
console.log(result)
```